juipyterbook rendering mathjax display equations in html
I'm writing an online jupyterbook with lots of mathematics. The rendering of equations is strange with in-line and display very different sizes. My assumption has been that mystyle.css should be respected by the _build html and it does propagate to the build directory fine, but either it's not respected or I've got the css wrong. Surely the latter.
Here is what I've been using, but it's not working...the color is there to tell me that something is happening and it isn't.
.math.inline .MathJax  {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

.math.display .MathJax  {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  color: #b22222;
}

I started with this:
/*.MathJax {
    font-size: 100% !important;
}*/

and the earlier, finer-grained .mathjax lines are my attempt to modify. There's no difference in behavior between the two approaches.
The image shows the result. Notice that the in-line math is large and the display math is tiny!
This is  part of the section that contains standard markdown math and corresponds to the attached screenshot. I've removed references to figures and extraneous stuff and classes.
## Work

Do you appreciate that the clay drop is, well different, but really the same as Herman and Blanche's bruised hands? They're both an impact and embedding of a projectile with a flexible target.

What happens in the inside, so to speak? Your hands are flexible and squish-able (the spring) and will compress with the ball's impact but will also apply a varying, but here an average force back at the ball, slowing it to a stop. That's represented by the $F_1$ while the depth through which that force pushes back is the length $d_1$ in the diagram. It turns out that the product of these two latter quantities is a very useful item.

The fancy way to speak about this $F_1 \times d_1$ quantity is in terms of "**work**" which means something very specific in physics. Work is in fact that product of (force $\times$ the distance through which the average force acts), $W=F\Delta x$. 

This is similar to the way that Impulse is the product of (force $\times$ the *time* through which the force acts). Sometimes the symbol $J$ stands for impulse, and so we'll name it in order to stand in comparison to work: $J=F\Delta t$. And here's the connection to our concern: that quantity $F\Delta x$ is equal to the change in the kinetic energy of the object, in this case, the baseball:

$$\begin{equation}
\text{work}=W=F\Delta x=\Delta(\dfrac{1}{2}mv^2).  (\#eq:work)
\end{equation}$$

which looks a lot like

$$\text{impulse}=J=F\Delta t =\Delta(mv)  \nonumber$$

This apparent partnership between time and space is related to the partnership between energy and momentum, as we’ll see a bit later.


Let's clear up a confusion from the last lesson.

This is the entire mystyle.css file which lives inside of the _static directory:
html {
font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
/*  font-family: sans-serif; */
/*  font-family: sans-serif; */
  font-size: 14px;
    line-height: 1.5;
/*  like newsprint */
    font-family: "PT Serif", 'Times New Roman', Times, serif;
    color: #1f0909;
    line-height: 1.5em;
}

body {
    background-color: #fcfcfb; !important;
}

<style>
strong { 
  font-weight: bold;
}
</style>

p.caption {
  font-size: 1.0rem;
  color: #777;
  margin-top: 10px;
}
p code {
  white-space: inherit;
}
pre {
  word-break: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
}
pre code {
  white-space: inherit;
}

/*.MathJax { font-size: 1.1em !important; }*/


         
    p {  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;
    color: #1f0909;
    font-weight: 500;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    line-height: 2.0rem;
    margin-top: 1.4rem;
    margin-bottom: 1.4rem;
    padding-right: 0;
    vertical-align: baseline;
}

/*.MathJax {
    font-size: 100% !important;
}*/

.math.inline .MathJax  {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
}

.math.display .MathJax  {
  font-size: 1.5rem !important;
  color: #b22222;
}

.admonition.danger {
    font-size: 1.1rem;
     font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
/*  font-family: "Palatino Linotype", "Book Antiqua", Palatino, serif;*/
/*   color: #b94a48;*/
/*   background-color: #e0e8f3;*/
/*   border-color: #eed3d7;*/
}

div.admonition, div.topic, blockquote {
    clear: left;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/* -- topics ---------------------------------------------------------------- */

div.topic {
    border: 1px solid #ccc;
    padding: 7px;
    margin: 10px 0 10px 0;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

p.topic-title {
    font-size: 1.1em;
    font-weight: bold;
    margin-top: 10px;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/* -- admonitions ----------------------------------------------------------- */

div.admonition {
    margin-top: 10px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    padding: 7px;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

div.admonition dt {
    font-weight: bold;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

p.admonition-title {
    margin: 0px 10px 5px 0px;
    font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.1rem;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

/*div.body centered {*/
div.body p.centered {
    text-align: center;
    margin-top: 25px;
         font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
}

div.admonition > p {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.1em;
     color: #686868;
      font-weight: 100;
     
}

blockquote.pull-quote,blockquote.epigraph,blockquote.highlights{
    font-size:1.25em;
    border-left:none;
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", "Lucida Grande", sans-serif;
     font-size: 1.0em;
    }
    
    blockquote p{
/*background-color:rgba(149,168,99,0.1);*/
/*border-left: 3px solid rgba(149,168,99,1.0);*/
/*     border-left: 5px solid rgba(182,83,84,1.0); */
/*    margin: 10px 0px 20px 0px;
    padding: 10px 0px 0px 40px;
      margin-left: 0px;
  padding-left: 60px; */
        font-size: 1.1rem;
        line-height: 1.2rem;  
        color: gray;
      font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
/*  font-style: italic; */
    }
    
    blockquote > p {
/*    padding: 15px;*/
    margin: 40px 0px;
      margin-left: 50px;
  margin-left: auto;
       padding-left: 15px;
                     padding-top: 25px;
              padding-bottom: 25px;
        background-color: #ffffff;
/*         border-left: 3px solid #ccc; */
/*    margin-left: 20px;*/
/*    padding-left: 20px;*/
font-size: 1.2rem;
line-height: 1.6rem;  
color: #212121;
    font-family: Helvetica, sans-serif; 
}


